# Duplicate tomcat logs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

Have spring boot app with only one dependency spring-boot-starter web
and want to see tomcat logs
for that i added to logging.properties that

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.maxDays = 90
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.maxDays = 90
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.bufferSize = 16384
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.maxDays = 90
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.OneLineFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.encoding = UTF-8

############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = \
   2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = \
   3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
#org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = FINE
```

and start my jar with -Djava.util.logging.config.file=PATH_TO_LOGGING_PROPERTIES
and all tomcat logs are duplicate

> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> [thread-missing] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> [thread-missing] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal Starting service [Tomcat]
> [thread-missing] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal Starting service [Tomcat]

how that can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The format of the default Tomcat configuration file is not supported by the default `java.util.logging` [`LogManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/LogManager.html). In the standard `LogManager` the properties `.handlers` and `handlers` are synonyms, hence the double console handler.

To use the default Tomcat configuration file, you need to use the [`ClassLoaderLogManager`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/api/org/apache/juli/ClassLoaderLogManager.html) (cf. [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/logging.html#Using_java.util.logging_(default))) by using:

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
```

Comment: in case when i delete one of the properties .handlers or handlers i don't see tomcat logs, that i see when they are both
and the same result with 
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager